# Flex android gallery share image to my app get filepath

Tags: android, apache-flex, gallery, share, filepath

When user open image on gallery on his android mobile he has an option to share this picture via apllications listed on this menu. So, i want to show my app in this share menu and when user click it - my app starts and gets filepath of image to be shared.
Now I trying these:

Writing on MyApp-app.xml

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
        <application>
            <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        </manifest> 
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

How to get a filepath of image to use it inside app?
I'm trying to write this code on mxml file:

```
protected function application_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(
                InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
        }

        private function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void
        {
            // some code to get filepath of Image
        }
```

Comment: Please post the Logcat output from the crash.

Comment: Sorry, but where can I find it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flex, but there should be a way to access the Logcat data for your device. If you're developing with Eclipse, there's a tab that shows Logcat output. There's a tutorial for Eclipse [here](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/).

Comment: Ok, now I understand, but in Flash Builder there are no Logcat window and no folder "Android" http://www.itcsolutions.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Eclipse_LogCat_View.jpg

Comment: I think you'll need to download the Android SDK and use the [`adb` tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (the command will be `adb logcat`) to retrieve the Logcat data. To answer your second question, the activity that's launched should receive an `Intent` that specifies the path for the image that the user chose in the gallery.

Comment: I've updated my post, there are no crash after I made some changes inside xml. Now main ask - how to get filepath of Image...

Answer (score 0):

I have a flex app that does something similar.  My app has a folder at the root of the sd card that it uses for storage.  I also wrote an android service as a native extension to my flex app.  When the user selects share from the android gallery, it starts my native extension service which then copies the selected image to a "share" folder inside my flex apps folder.  When my flex app starts or becomes active, it checks this folder for any files.

Its not the most elegant solution in the world but it works for me.